# Just-in-Time debugger dialog box stop my Web Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, installation, iis

after installing  SharePoint 2016 and SQL server 2016 
this popup message coming every time I open any web application on SharePoint even the Central administration
  [image]

it also reflects the IIS and stop the running application

[image]

I already searched for many solutions to stop this but it did not work with me 
even this solution did not work:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

id there is ant other solution  please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use the registry editor to delete the following registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
```

On a 64-bit operating system also delete the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
```

Comment: Done But still no success

Comment: also disabled from IE Advanced settings